# Is there a way in SQL to sum the contents of a column, where another column = something and subtract to this number, another operation?

Tags: sql

Right now I have this:

```
  query1 = "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table WHERE column2 = 'EUR'"

  query2 = "SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table WHERE column4 = 'EUR'"

  result = query1 - query2
```

I would like to merge it into one single query so it looks something like this:

```
 query = "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table WHERE column2 = 'EUR' - 
              SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table WHERE column4 = 'EUR' "
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: please share sample data with insert scripts and output you are expecting from sample data,

Comment: you can probably use a simple `case expression`

Comment: Use Case or IIF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should hopefully work

```
select 
    Sum(case when column2='EUR' then column1 end) -
    Sum(case when column4='EUR' then column3 end)
from table
```